# Adding animation at start up using an array of images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, animation

I'm new to iphone app development and I'm trying to add an image to the start of my app. I've created an array of images which when iterated should create an animation.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{

    animation = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    animation.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
                                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"panda1.png"],                                  
                                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"panda2.png"],                              
                                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"panda3.png"], nil];

    animation.animationRepeatCount = 2;
    animation.animationDuration = 2;
    [animation startAnimating];

    [self.view addSubview:animation];

    [animation release];

    //for loading the webpage at start up

    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://projects.seng.uvic.ca/fatpanda/m/most_recent.php";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //load the request in the UIWebView
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];   
}
```

The reason I release the animation at the end of this is because I'd like to remove the last image so I can replace it with a view of a website in a UIWebView and have that visible at the end. The code above compiles but when I run it no images appear but the website does.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, i think your frame is ending up all zeros.

```
UIImage * first = [UIImage imageNamed:@"panda1.png"]
animation = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:first];
animation.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
                                             first,                                  
                                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"panda2.png"],                              
                                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"panda3.png"], nil];
```

Also...
releasing the animaiton will not remove it from the superview.  in fact calling addSubview will increase the reference count to the UIImageView and releasing it is the correct thing to do.  When you want to to remove from the view it you will have to find it again in the list of subviews and either hide it or call removeFromSuperview.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I'm having issues removing it though. I've tried  [annimation removeFromSuperview]; and annimation.hidden = YES; at the end of the function ((I also moved the  [animation release]; to the end)and they cause the animation to not show up at all. I even tried putting in a sleep before reomoving them.

Comment: sleep won't help. Schedule it on an NSTimer.

Comment: I created a timer timer =  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 3 target: self selector: @selector(removeAnimation:) userInfo: nil repeats: NO];

And then my function removeAnimation has [animation release];[animation removeFromSuperview];

It appears it removes the animation but it exits out of the app at the same time.